# How do I remove a package with Chef?

Tags: chef

I am trying to remove packages using a chef.
i.e. remove java 1.6 and install java 1.4

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
package "sun-java6-jdk" do
  action :remove
end
```

See http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Resources#Resources-Package

Comment: Thank you, I read that page and guess my brain was not engaged.